# Excel array countif formula

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, countif

I want to use COUNTIF function to evaluate how many items out of 2,0,0,5 are greater than 2? In Countif function, first argument is range and second is criteria. I have tried the below formula. Even tried using Ctrl+Shift+Enter at the end to evaluate. But doesn't seem to work.

```
=COUNTIF({"2","0","0","5"},">2")
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`COUNTIF` doesn't accept array constants (as far as I know). Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--({2,0,0,5}>2))
```

---

You could also create a countif-style formula like this (the combination ctrl+shift+enter):

```
=COUNT(IF({2,0,0,5}>2,1,""))
```

Comment: Agreed, all of the "IFS" family of functions are the same, the "range" arguments do need to be worksheet ranges, not arrays

Comment: Thanks this wokred. Any other way I can use Countif only to solve my problem ?

Comment: @SurbhiManocha, as barry said, it seems like you can't use `COUNTIF`, but you can use `COUNT` with `IF` -- see my edit for details if that helps

Comment: @SurbhiManocha Not with an array constant.  You could put the values into separate cells (eg = countif(a1:a5,">2").

Answer (score 3):

Recommended reading: 
[Array vs Range](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/407180-i-want-understand-difference-between-range-array.html)

Some functions like Offset, SumIf, CountIf, SumIfs, and CountIfs are designed to operate only on (multi-cell) range objects. Sum, SumProduct, Frequency, Linest, lookup functions, etc. take both range and array objects.

Array means: **{2,0,0,5}**

Range means:

[image]

To use countif, you have to use range in cells, defining the array in the formula on the go will not work.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A4,">"&2)
```

Comment: I am using this in VBA with Evaluate formula. In range, I want to pass values instead of range. For Example :  EVALUATE(sum{1,2,3})) is working fine but EVALUATE(sumif{1,2,3},">1") is not working.

Comment: Because {1,2,3} does not work with sumifs. Please read up: https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/407180-i-want-understand-difference-between-range-array.html

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a few years old, but I ended up here with a similar problem (how to use arrays, not ranges, with countif).

Although my end goal was a little different (I wanted to find items common to two arrays), I figure the workaround I came up with might be useful for others:  I ended up using the "match" function coupled with "isnumber".  The formula looked like this:

```
=isnumber(match({a},{b},0))
```

this will return an array of true/false which corresponds to the values in {a} that are also in {b}.  In case it wasn't clear, {a} and {b} are arrays...