# Excel Countif - parsing arguments with functions without helper row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm trying to use countif function to count the number of bedrooms on a large rent roll sheet (hundreds of entries).

Is it possible to do this without using a helper column?  I tried but get an error.  Not sure why.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your helper column is Column C? What does the data in column B represent? X bedrooms and Y bathrooms?

Comment: `=COUNTIF(B2:B7,"1x*")`

Comment: @PeterT Correct "Beds"x"Baths"

Comment: @BigBen Your formula worked.  Do you know what is wrong with my version? Can you explain?

Comment: You could use SUMPRODUCT instead of COUNTIF with an approach like that: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(--(LEFT($B$2:$B$7))=E3))`, but that's overkill, a wildcard is the way to go.

Comment: For more explanation on why COUNTIF doesn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095934/excel-array-countif-formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a wildcard:

```
=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$7,E3&"x*")
```

[image]

*Included the `x` just in case the number of bedrooms goes past 9, but you might be able to drop it.

For more detail on why `COUNTIF` with an array doesn't work, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48095934/excel-array-countif-formula).